# Magento2 export mutiple pdf

Tags: magento2.4.3.p1

I have this file, if i choose 2 order it will export only 1 file pdf for both. How can export 2 files pdf for each in 1 time?

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection as OrderCollection;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Pdfinvoices extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\PdfDocumentsMassAction
{
    /**
     * Authorization level of a basic admin session
     */
    const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Magento_Sales::invoice';

    /**
     * @var FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;

    /**
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $dateTime;

    /**
     * @var Invoice
     */
    protected $pdfInvoice;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DateTime $dateTime
     * @param FileFactory $fileFactory
     * @param Invoice $pdfInvoice
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        FileFactory $fileFactory,
        Invoice $pdfInvoice
    ) {
        $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->pdfInvoice = $pdfInvoice;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $filter);
    }

    /**
     * Print invoices for selected orders
     *
     * @param AbstractCollection $collection
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function massAction(AbstractCollection $collection)
    {
        $invoicesCollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->setOrderFilter(['in' => $collection->getAllIds()]);
        if (!$invoicesCollection->getSize()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('There are no printable documents related to selected orders.'));
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath($this->getComponentRefererUrl());
        }
        $pdf = $this->pdfInvoice->getPdf($invoicesCollection->getItems());
        $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

        return $this->fileFactory->create(
            sprintf('invoice%s.pdf', $this->dateTime->date('Y-m-d_H-i-s')),
            $fileContent,
            DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
            'application/pdf'
        );
    }
}
```